# When requesting github to get access token i was getting "not found" error as response

Tags: github, access-token

here is the request:(i required node-fetch as fetch to do http requests on the server)

```
const { code } = req.body;

const data = new FormData();
data.append("client_id", process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID);
data.append("client_secret", process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET);
data.append("code", code);
data.append("redirect_uri", process.env.GITHUB_REDIRECT_URL);

fetch(`https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: data,
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

here is the response:
{ error: 'Not Found' }